# Hilighting div tag in Masterpage on redirection to content page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a link in Master page within a div tag. I want to highlight the div when I am clicking the link, in order to redirect to some content page.

**I have written the following code:**

```
<li>
    <div id="div_test" runat="server">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_test_menu" Font-Underline="false" 
            ForeColor="Black" runat="server" Text="Test Link"
            CausesValidation="false" onclick="lnk_test_menu_Click1" >
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Code in the cs page:**

```
   protected void lnk_test_menu_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        div_test.Attributes.Add("class", "testSelected"); 
        Response.Redirect(Test.aspx");           
   }
```

The div in the master page is not being selected on redirection.

Could anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

**First Method:** Using jQuery

Remove runat="server" from div.

```
<div id="div_test">
```

&

Place this code on the Test.aspx page.

```
$(function(){
  $("#div_test").addClass("testSelected");
});
```

**Second Method:**

```
protected void lnk_test_menu_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Test.aspx");
}
```

On Page_Load Event of Test.aspx page, set:

```
HtmlGenericControl div_test = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("div_test");
div_test.Attributes.Add("class", "testSelected");
```

Comment: Thanks for the the answer. But its giving a error. It is not finding the Master page div_test from the content page Test.aspx.

Comment: I have tried the code in page load but the Master page object is returned as null.